# Angular2 not updating/transpiling/compiling correctly

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm a beginner with this framework and I'm frustrated. I've just about given up on learning Angular2 for now, but can someone please explain to me how I can copy line for line the code in the docs and it still not work?

Earlier on I've seen instances of it calling classes that I've long gotten rid of. I reinstalled everything, upgraded npm to 3.1.0, made sure node is up to date, and tried again. Maybe I shouldn't have taken this unfinished language up when I'm a beginner (no idea how to debug), but I'm speaking of the 'Heroes' tutorial on their site.

The view is supposed to show "Loading..." then get info from the app component. In the beginning, it loads as it should, but then I get to that "Master/Detail" in the tutorial and it all goes to boom boom. Let me show you my code:

[Well this is the app component. This code worked at first until I got deeper into the tutorial. I go back to this code, and it doesn't work anymore. What gives? Followed the doc to the 't'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P7NZ.jpg)

[I had to comment out this code because it made the app mysteriously stop working. Stopped when I passed the array in the constant HEROES to the property heroes. Again, this is in the docs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J55VA.jpg)

The index and module files are fine. I've stopped and restarted at least four times and I've about had it. I think I'll just finish learning the regular MEAN stack. Unless someone can come up with a reason why all of this is happening? I see no fault in my code. And even if there was, changing my code or undoing changes should produce results. IT DOESN'T!

I'm thinking it's more to do with the transpiling process, and it not updating TS to JS properly? Which could explain why I was still seeing error messages saying it was trying to call classes I've already gotten rid of.

Comment: can you copy the code text please? image screenshots aren't good enough

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser? If you think it's the transpiler, what it is saying when it transpiles the TS?

Comment: I'd love to help, but there is definitely not enough information on here. What are the error messages? Are you getting the errors in the during the build or in the browser? If you can host your whole project up on github and give us a link, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok I just pushed it to GitHub https://github.com/Lloydinator/quickstartprobs.

Comment: I'm no longer getting errors that I had before because I cleared everything, reinstalled and upgraded npm and started fresh. So unfortunately I can't tell you the exact errors I saw.